# Scope variable not updating in $scope.$watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a watcher on a $scope variable which sets off a function to change the $scope variable to the beginning of the week of the date chosen. The function is returning the correct date but when I try to set the $scope variable to that date the view does not update. But checking it inside the inspector the $scope variable is changed but the view never updates. Here is the $watch function:

```
angular.module('hansenApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('hansenApp').controller('DatepickerCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.startDate = new Date();
    $scope.endDate = new Date();

    $scope.status = {
        startOpened: false,
        endOpened: false,
    };

    $scope.openStart = function ($event) {
        $scope.status.startOpened = true;
    };

    $scope.openEnd = function ($event) {
        $scope.status.endOpened = true;
    };

    $scope.$watch('startDate', function (dateVal) {
        var oldDate = new Date(dateVal);
        var tempDate = getStartDateOfWeek(dateVal);

        if (oldDate.getTime() != tempDate.getTime()) {
            $scope.startDate = tempDate;
        }
    });

    $scope.$watch('endDate', function (dateVal) {
        var oldDate = new Date(dateVal);
        var tempDate = getEndDateOfWeek(dateVal);

        if ($scope.endDate.getTime() != tempDate.getTime()) {
            $scope.endDate = tempDate;
        }
    });

    function getStartDateOfWeek(date) {
        var ISOweekStart = date;
        ISOweekStart.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay());
        return ISOweekStart;
    }

    function getEndDateOfWeek(date) {
        var ISOweekEnd = date;
        ISOweekEnd.setDate(date.getDate() + (6 - date.getDay()));
        return ISOweekEnd;
    }
});
```

**Edit 1:** Here's the view:

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="endDate" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="endDate" is-open="status.endOpened" close-text="Close" placeholder="End Date:" runat="server" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openEnd($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: can you please update your question to reflect the problem more specifically now since you've pasted the code?

Comment: You should be getting an infdig error on your console. You shouldn't $watch a variable that you also modify inside $watch, use a different name

Comment: aside: `if (oldDate.getTime() != tempDate.getTime()) ` == `if (oldDate-tempDate) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not change the reference of the date, but just the value of it.

A Date is an object in javascript, hence if you do not change the reference (replace it by a new Date() object) the angular change detector will not trigger again.
So you will have to replace the startDate by a completely new instance of a javascript date with the given properties.

So replace

```
var ISOweekEnd = date;
```

by

```
var ISOweekEnd = new Date();
```

Comment: Great! Works! Thanks a lot.